# Hailstone Sequence, recursive, missing the 1 case

Tags: java, recursion, sequence, collatz

I have the following hailstone sequence code, which works for all numbers, beside the sequence of 1:

```java
public class Recursion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hailstone(16);  // prints  16 8 4 2 1
        hailstone(1);  //prints just 1 instead of 1 4 2 1
    }

    public static void hailstone(int seed) {
        String str = "" + seed;

        if (seed == 1) {
            System.out.print(str);
        } else {
            if (seed % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(str + " ");
                hailstone(seed / 2);
            } else {
                System.out.print(str + " ");
                hailstone((3 * seed) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I bypass this special case while staying in recursive method and in void?

I'm not allowed using any kind of loops.

Comment: The code is correct. A hailstone sequence ends at 1, and if that's the first element, the entire sequence is 1.

Comment: I've been taught that if the seed is 1, then that's a special case

Comment: @NathanHughes from https://plus.maths.org/content/mathematical-mysteries-hailstone-sequences: *it seems that all hailstone sequences eventually end in the endless cycle [ 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1,...]*. This would cause an infinite loop if implemented by a loop, or stack overflow if implemented by recursion. So in a program implementation after the 1st sequence [4, 2, 1] the program must stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end a small note for your information (I am surprised to see all static in the code).

To the point. You say that:

- you cannot change the signature
- you must use recursion (no loops allowed)

Define a static boolean and add a condition for the case you reach the number 1.
The last sequence in the hailstone sequence is an infinte pattern. The special case is because you need the program to stop at some point. Here I simply use a boolean to print the pattern once after the number 1 has been reached for the first time. I hope the code is self explaining.

```
public class Recursion {

    private static boolean reached = false; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //hailstone(16);  // prints  16 8 4 2 1
        hailstone(1);  //prints just 1 instead of 1 4 2 1
    }

    public static void hailstone(int seed) {
        String str = "" + seed;

        if (seed == 1 && reached) {
            System.out.print(str);
        } else if (seed == 1 && !reached) {
            System.out.print(str + " ");
            reached = true;
            hailstone((3 * seed) + 1);
        } else {
            if (seed % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(str + " ");
                hailstone(seed / 2);
            } else {
                System.out.print(str + " ");
                hailstone((3 * seed) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: In Java usually it is not a good practice to code a lot of static members/methods. It could be designed better I believe. I did not want to go into this because I do not want to confuse and I would like to focus on the question.
There is a downside to code it the way I did for example. Simply try to call `hailstone(16)` and `hailstone(1)` subsequently and you will see what I mean; this is because the boolean had already been set from the first sequence calculation. You would need to reset it to false again. There are better ways to design this...

Answer (score 2):

`1` is the exit point of your recursion, that's why you can't make it also behave like an entry point. 
What if you change the exit point? Make `2` the pre-exit point:

```
public static void hailstone(int seed) {
    String str = "" + seed;

    if (seed == 2) {
        System.out.print(str + " 1");
    } else {
        if (seed % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(str + " ");
            hailstone(seed / 2);
        } else {
            System.out.print(str + " ");
            hailstone((3 * seed) + 1);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    hailstone(16);
    System.out.println();
    hailstone(15);
    System.out.println();
    hailstone(1);
    System.out.println();
}
```

will print:

```
16 8 4 2 1
15 46 23 70 35 106 53 160 80 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
1 4 2 1
```